# Info Path cant retrieve SQL data after publishing the form

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath2010

I created a form in info path which will connect to SQL DB and all connectivity are fine. I preview the form and all SQL data retrieved fine without any issue.

I published the form but when end-users try to load the form, it was shown an error like (An error occurred querying a data source. An error occurred while using the form. For more information, contact the site administrator).

Means I can only retrieve the data while I am at info path and previewing the form but not after the publish.

Is there any things which need to be allowed at SharePoint level to connect to connect to SQL DB which I used in the info path.

Please help and advice .. what could be the issue ??

Answer (score 0):

I would think about permissions on the database. 
Have you tried to access the form from the browser with the same user you used in InfoPath designer?

Comment: Hi Brother, thanks for your comments and update. the user which I used to connect my form while doing the design in the info path is different than the one which I used in the browser as the one which I used via the browser was Active directory account and SQL was local SQL user not with windows authentication mode.